# Keyboard delay Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

As strange as it may sound, I would like to deliberately introduce a delay into keyboard input on Windows. I am NOT referring to the delay rate or the repeat rate, both of which I am quite familiar. Rather, I would like to introduce, for example, a 1 -50ms delay from when the keyboard key reaches its respective actuation point and when the computer enters that keycode into whatever stream/registry/(i don't pretend to know exactly how that low level works). Don't tell me it is not possible. It is obviously possible, if extremely difficult. If there is a registry editor solution, that would be ideal. Thanks for indulging me

Comment: Not sure this is what you're looking for, but I use this freeware everyday, and it's an absolute gem: http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/ClavierDoc.php?sLang=en. Read the feature page and see for yourself if it can do what you're looking for or not.